# WebForms Eval() with function and others variables

Tags: c#, webforms

```
<%
    DateTime date;
    var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");

    DateTime.TryParseExact(Eval("pubDate").ToString(), "dd MMM", culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);

    var b = date.ToString();
 %>
```

I'm trying to Eval a date from wordpress feed inside a asp:ListView. What i want is to 'return' *b* to the ItemTemplate, but i keep getting this error:

**{"The methods of data association such as Eval (), XPath () and Bind () can only be used in the context of a control data binding."}**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the .aspx

```
<%# ToDate(Eval("pubDate")) %>
```

on.aspx.cs

```
    protected string ToDate(object wordpressDate)
    {
        DateTime date;
        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");

        DateTime.TryParse(wordpressDate.ToString(), culture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date);

        return date.ToString("dd MMM");
    }
```